# F# NLog config file

Tags: f#, xsd, config, nlog

I'm trying to use NLog in an F# console application, I've managed to get it working using a configuration section in App.config however I can't get it working using a stand-alone NLog.config file.  My NLog.config file is in the app route, just under App.config and the contents are:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throwExceptions="true">
    <targets>
        <target name="stdFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:/temp/compliant.log"/>
        <target name="display" xsi:type="OutputDebugString"/>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="compliant.mail.*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="stdFile,display" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, intellisense isn't working for the xml even though I have included the xsd. :(

Answer (score 1):

In your project, in the Properties for NLog.config, do you have NLog.config marked as "Copy Always"?

Comment: It was set to Do Not Copy.  I tried setting it to Copy Always but that didn't help :(

Comment: That's the only thing I can think of at the moment.  When NLog (or lognet for that matter) for me, it is usually because NLog.config cannot be found.  If I think of anything else, I'll post back.

Comment: Sorry, I have left this hanging and moved on to another part of my project but I will get on it again next week and let you know.  Thanks for your response.